# Filling a dataframe column with values from another column, based on values from a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like the following. I created the last 3 columns based on unique values from the column `RefIDPrefix`.

| RefIDPrefix | RefIDNumber | GO | PMID | Reactome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GO | 12345 |  |  |  |
| PMID | 23456 |  |  |  |
| Reactome | 34567 |  |  |  |
| GO | 45678 |  |  |  |
| GO | 56789 |  |  |  |
| PMID | 67890 |  |  |  |

I want to fill the last 3 columns like the following. Basically, based on the value in `RefIDPrefix`, I want to take the value in `RefIDNumber` and put it in the correct column corresponding to `RefIDPrefix`.

| RefIDPrefix | RefIDNumber | GO | PMID | Reactome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GO | 12345 | 12345 |  |  |
| PMID | 23456 |  | 23456 |  |
| Reactome | 34567 |  |  | 34567 |
| GO | 45678 | 45678 |  |  |
| GO | 56789 | 56789 |  |  |
| PMID | 67890 |  | 67890 |  |

I have been trying to do this for a while but haven't been able to figure out how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to build the columns from `RefIDPrefix` and [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) it back to the original `df`

```
df.join(df.pivot(columns='RefIDPrefix', values='RefIDNumber').fillna(''))
```

Output:

```
  RefIDPrefix  RefIDNumber       GO     PMID Reactome
0          GO        12345  12345.0                  
1        PMID        23456           23456.0         
2    Reactome        34567                    34567.0
3          GO        45678  45678.0                  
4          GO        56789  56789.0                  
5        PMID        67890           67890.0
```

### Edit

For the display format of the numbers in new columns (currently displayed like `float` number with decimal point), if your `RefIDNumber` column is actually in string, the numbers in new column will also be in string and have no decimal point (like integers).

However, if `RefIDNumber` is in numeric format (most probably in positive numbers for ID numbers), we can retain the numbers as `integer` by fine-tuning the [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) part, as follows:

```
df.join(df.pivot(columns='RefIDPrefix', values='RefIDNumber').fillna(-1, downcast='infer').replace(-1, ''))
```

Output:

```
  RefIDPrefix  RefIDNumber     GO   PMID Reactome
0          GO        12345  12345                
1        PMID        23456         23456         
2    Reactome        34567                  34567
3          GO        45678  45678                
4          GO        56789  56789                
5        PMID        67890         67890
```